# Condition in sql query with sql join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, 'salary' and 'conversion_rate'.

Salary table contain salary of each employee for each month, there will be only one row for each employee for a month. But for all employees month can be same like 2021-Dec salary for all employees.
e.g:

| name | date | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | 2021-12-25 | 50000 |
| john | 2021-11-25 | 50000 |
| harry | 2021-12-25 | 50000 |
| harry | 2021-11-25 | 50000 |

Second Table is conversion_rate.
it contains salary conversion rates like dollar or euro rate for each month but it is possible that for a given month there is no conversion rate. like for example for 2021-Dec there is no conversion rate available.
e.g:

| rate | date |
| --- | --- |
| 170.23 | 2021-12-25 |
| 160.40 | 2021-11-25 |
| 174.44 | 2021-08-25 |

Question:
I want to join each row in salary table with its conversion rate in conversion_rate table on the basis of date column.
but if there is no date available in conversion_rate table then it should pick previous nearest date and its conversion rate?

for Example:

```
select name, salary, rate 
from salary as s
left join conversion_rate as c on (c.date = s.date || c.date < s.date)
```

I want to do this in sql query.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The tables are tiny, so you may use

```sql
SELECT name, 
       salary, 
       ( SELECT rate
         FROM conversion_rate AS c
         WHERE c.`date` <= s.`date`
         ORDER BY c.`date` DESC LIMIT 1) AS rate 
FROM salary AS s;
```

The index `` conversion_rate (`date`) `` is valuable.